# PHP form accepts login with blank fields

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a contact form where you have to register with your name, e-mail etc. After succesfull entering those infos, you get a mail with a generated password. Then you can got to a login screen, where you have to enter your e-mail and the password that you got via mail. Is mail and password correct it displays a link where you can download a brochure.

So far so good, when i enter false infos, i can’t login. But when i enter nothing at all, the download link will still appear.

```
   <form method="POST" action="broschuere_download.php">              
                        <label> E-Mail </label>
                        <input type="text" <?php echo "name='email' value='$email' "?>/>

                        <label> Passwort </label>
                        <input type="text" <?php echo "name='password' value='$password' "?>/>    

                        <input class="button" type="submit" <?php echo "name='submit' value='Zur Broschüre' "?> style="margin-left: 140px; width: 276px;"/>
                    </form>  

                   <?php
                    // MySQL
                    $dbhost = "host";
                    $dbuser = "user";
                    $dbpass = "pass";
                    $dbname = "name";
                    $email = $_POST["email"];
                    $password = $_POST["password"];

                    $verbindung = mysql_connect($dbhost,
                    $dbuser,$dbpass);

                    mysql_select_db($dbname)
                    or die ("Die Datenbank existiert nicht.");

                    $abfrage = "SELECT email, password FROM besco_passwords";

                    $ergebnis = mysql_query($abfrage);

                    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($ergebnis)){
                        if ($email === "$row->email" && $password === "$row->password"){
                            print "<h1 style='margin-bottom: 0px;'> Vielen Dank für Ihr Interesse! <br> Bitte klicken Sie hier zum Download der Broschüre! </h1><br>  ";            
                            print "Download: Rechtsklick -> 'Ziel speichern unter'<br /><br />";
                            print "<a href='http://www.test.de' target='_blank'> Broschüre </a>"; 
                        }  
                        else{
                            print "";
                        }
                    }//endwhile

                    ?>
```

I am not that good at php, but i allready looked up my problem and tried to fix it myself. i also found some similar scripts but they didn’t work for me.

(*added fake login details and link for stackoverflow*)

Comment: for starters, do not use `mysql_*` functions, and then, you should edit your query probably, to include a `WHERE` clause

Comment: Also you should _never_ store a user password in a database! That is a huge security risk and not necessary. Instead you store a _hash_ of the password and compare that hash to the fresh hash of a password provided at login time. That way you do not leak passwords even if your system gets compromised. See this good resource for an example and an explanation: https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm

Comment: The loop `while($row = mysql_fetch_object($ergebnis)){` will not be entered at all, if no match is found in the database. That means you do not react at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your input inputs like this :

```
$error=false;

if(isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $email = $_POST["email"];
} else {
    $error=true;
}

if(isset($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $email = $_POST["email"];
} else {
    $error=true;
}

if(!$error) {
    $verbindung = mysql_connect($dbhost,
    $dbuser,$dbpass);

    mysql_select_db($dbname)
    or die ("Die Datenbank existiert nicht.");

    $abfrage = "SELECT email, password FROM besco_passwords";

    $ergebnis = mysql_query($abfrage);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($ergebnis)){
        if ($email === "$row->email" && $password === "$row->password"){
            print "<h1 style='margin-bottom: 0px;'> Vielen Dank für Ihr Interesse! <br> Bitte klicken Sie hier zum Download der Broschüre! </h1><br>  ";            
            print "Download: Rechtsklick -> 'Ziel speichern unter'<br /><br />";
            print "<a href='http://www.test.de' target='_blank'> Broschüre </a>"; 
        }  
        else{
            print "";
        }
    }//endwhile
} else {
    echo "You should fill all the fields.";
}
```

Comment: While this does fix the mentioned effect in some cases it is not a good solution to the OPs issue. The problem is that no working handling of flow cases is implemented which your suggestion does not fix.